# Potential bug with NSDateFormatter in iOS6. Has anyone else encountered this?

Tags: objective-c, date, ios6, nsdateformatter

We'll get straight to it.  Here's the code snippet:

```
NSString *dateString = @"4001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@ -- %@", dateString, date);
```

The result when building for iPhone 5.1 Simulator (or iOS 5.1 device):

```
4001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z -- 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

The result when building for iPhone 6.0 Simulator (or iOS 6 device):

```
4001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z -- 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

Note the discrepancy in the output years (after the "--").

We've determined that in iOS 6, the date formatter subtracts 2000 years from any date beyond the year 3512 (1500 years from now).

Has anyone else experienced this and/or have an elegant workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: I was curious enough to try this... and yes, I can verify the difference between the 5.1 and 6.0 simulators. Haven't the foggiest notion about why, though... at least not yet.

Comment: I think this was already noted by someone else.  Perhaps you should create an ios6-bugs tag or some such.

Comment: Thank you for the independent verification, @JereKäpyaho.

Comment: Verify on a device, iOS simulators have many many bugs.

Comment: @stackmonster, please notice that I did say I tested on device.

Comment: really? quote your post.

Comment: @stackmonster Look below the first code block: "The result when building for iPhone 5.1 Simulator **(or iOS 5.1 device)**:"

Comment: I opened a bug with Apple: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=2059402

Comment: You're not alone, it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612585/ios-6-nsdateformatter