# dateFrom String returns incorrect date

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6, ios6.1

I have been struggling to figure out why `dateFromString method` returns wrong date.

Here is the code :

```
NSDate *secondDate = [df dateFromString:@"12.31.9999"];
```

And the output for it is as below :

```
1999-12-31 07:00:00 +0000
```

Is it the problem with the method? The same works fine in iOS5. The issues is only in iOS6.

Comment: what's your date format ?

Comment: @DharmbirChoudhary It's "MM.dd.yyyy" (MAC OS version 10.8.4)

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12612585/ios-6-nsdateformatter

Comment: how are you initializing your date formatter?

Comment: @nielsbot I have set the time zone to localTimeZone only.

[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

Comment: Btw--if you want a date in the distant future, just use the distantFuture method of NSDate

Comment: @GabrielePetronella 

NSDateFormatter *df  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [df setDateFormat:@"MM.dd.yyyy"];
     [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

Comment: I deleted my other comments... What I said applies to the hour being off by 7 hours, but I also see the year came out wrong.

Comment: @nielsbot The dates come from web services. I have just tried these two line of code, whether at least they work fine or not. It failed. The question that I have asked here is completely hard coded to see the output.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. hope this will solve your problem

```
- (NSString *) convertedDate : (NSString *) dateStr {

  NSString *finalDate = dateStr;
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd"];//In which formate you are date is passing 
  NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:finalDate];

  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];// in which formate date you want 
  NSString *dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
  return dateString;
}
```